# Shipping calendar with hundreds of thousands of rows over 10 years How to delete in bulk?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

Found that some of my plants were using SP Calendar to identify the trucks that needed to be filled for the day.  There may be 10-30 trucks a day and this has been in use since 2007.

Porting to a new version I would like to lose all trucks in dates earlier than this year.  I want to reduce my data stored in the SQL server as the final goal in that I want the data removed and not hidden.  The ERP has records of all these transactions.

Excel cannot accept the volume, already tried that idea.  Or do you think I should make an ungodly volume as a upper limit?

Any other ideas?

TIA

Comment: You can use the built in Information management policies in the list settings to handle this. Setup a retention policy on the list that after 1 year, items are deleted.

Comment: I have investigated your reply and am not sure that my rule will only be carried over to all other calendar lists on the site.